# SPARQL Query final label

Tags: sparql

I have a SPARQL Query that returns the Europe capitals and their population. The query looks like this:

```
 select ?s ?pop
 where {
    ?s <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/populationTotal> ?pop . 
    ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/place> 
 }
```

In this state, it returns the names of the cities in the following form: e.g. `"<http://dbpedia.org/resource/London>"` and what I want is to display only `London` in this case. So, is there a way I can tell SPARQL that I want only the final label?

I am querying against this endpoint: `https://rdf.s4.ontotext.com/4730361296/demo01/repositories/test01`

Answer (score 0):

The advice here is similar to other questions - use SPARQL to inspect the data.  So first try this query to see if there are any label properties defined:

```
select *
where {
  ?s <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/populationTotal> ?pop . 
  ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/place> .
  ?s ?p ?o .
}
```

In this case you'll find that no label properties have been defined for `place` class definitions.  If desired you can take the local name - the text after the last slash (or hash) as the name.  Try this query:

```
select *
where {
  ?s <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/populationTotal> ?pop . 
  ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/place> .
  BIND(REPLACE(xsd:string(?s), ".*[/#]", "") AS ?label)
}
```